# EF with Lazy Loading. Can't Delete a Record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Receiving the following error when I try to delete my Teacher record.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Department_dbo.Teacher_TeacherID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "MySchoolBook", table "dbo.Department", column 'TeacherID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

My Teacher Model:

```
public class Teacher : Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TeacherID { get; set; }

    public Guid? AccountID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }

    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
}
```

My Department Model:

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    public Guid? TeacherID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Administrator { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .HasOptional(d => d.Administrator);
        }
```

Edit:

What I would like to happen is when I delete my Teacher record, for my Department's TeacherID Column to go NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I would like to happen is when I delete my Teacher record, for my
>   Department's TeacherID Column to go NULL.

You must set the `TeacherID` to `null` manually. EF doesn't do this for you:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var teacher = context.Teachers
        .SingleOrDefault(t => t.TeacherID == teacherToDeleteID);

    if (teacher != null)
    {
        var departments = context.Departments
            .Where(d => d.TeacherID == teacherToDeleteID);
        foreach (var department in departments)
            department.TeacherID = null;

        context.Teachers.Remove(teacher);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can try to remove the loop and only load the departments into the context. It is possible that automatic relationship fixup will set the `TeacherID` FK to `null` when you delete the teacher, I am not sure though:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var teacher = context.Teachers
        .SingleOrDefault(t => t.TeacherID == teacherToDeleteID);
    if (teacher != null)
    {
        context.Departments.Where(d => d.TeacherID == teacherToDeleteID).Load();
        context.Teachers.Remove(teacher);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of this. Thanks.

Comment: @WesleyPattison: You could alternatively try the code in my Edit section above. It's probably not a big win performancewise. Let me know if that works because I am not sure if it does.

Comment: It works, but as you mentioned, I don't think performance would be the greatest. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: @WesleyPattison: Aside from using direct SQL that updates the FK to `NULL` or a Stored Procedure I don't think there is a better way. With pure EF you must load the departments into the context.